# Stop "Excel formula or sheet contains the name" dialog

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

When I want to copy a sheet (within the same file, so simply using left mouse button and Ctrl) in Excel 2007, I get this pop up dialog:

[image: Yes / No dialog]

where *Author* is a specific field *somewhere* in the sheet I'm editing.

The catch is that I cannot get rid of this dialog. If I press Yes, I get the same dialog with a different field. I have no idea how many fields there are in this sheet, but these dialogs just keep popping up...

If I press No, I get:

[image: Name conflict]

If I press Cancel (I don't even know what I'm changing, so I don't want to change it!), I get:

[image: Name not valid]

even though I pressed Cancel! (Same happens if I press OK without entering anything. If I enter something, I go back to the first dialog with the next field.)

Since I want to get out of this, I use Task Manager to quit Excel and then get:

[image: Cannot quit Excel!]

To prevent me banging my head on the table, **can anyone tell me how I can change the Excel sheet so that these pop ups stop occurring?**

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? Two copies of the same sheet in the same workbook? (to close excel, use task manager->end process for excel.exe)

Comment: Yes, two copies of the same sheet. Thanks for the Task Manager tip, that is exactly what I had to do.

Comment: And so it's clear, you right clicked on the sheet tab, clicked move or copy, checked the create a copy box, picked your location, hit OK, and got these errors?

Comment: @soandos: actually, I just LMBed+Ctrl, I will update the question.

Comment: Try it my way and see it if works.

Comment: @soandos: done it, same behaviour.

Comment: Are these things defined names on the workbook? If so, they will cause your error.

Comment: The best way to handle the first message box is to click Yes. You will get that message for every similarly-defined & used name... Use the Name Manager to see how many named ranges you have.

Comment: @soandos: well, I guess they must be but it was not my spreadsheet so I don't know where they are.

Comment: @RachelHettinger: thanks, how can I use the Name Manager?

Comment: In the formula's tab, click name manager.

Comment: @soandos: thanks, that name manager is where I can delete all these references! If you make that into a good answer, I will accept it.

Comment: If you ever come across countless dialogs that you just want to answer yes (or no) to, just hold Alt+Y or Alt+N or Alt+anotherletter, whichever the accelerator might be. You'll be done in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Formulas -> Name Manager**, select the whole list in the pop up box and press **Delete**.

You may also need to close and re-open the file to get rid of these messages.

Comment: @soandos - if you enter your own version of this answer, I will delete mine and accept yours.

Comment: With me it only worked when I close and reopen Excel after deleting the entries.

Comment: How do you get there since the menus are inaccessible ?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, but Name Manager does not reveal all the names embedded in the sheet. Somehow I got a bunch of hidden names in the worksheet.

Here is how to unhide them

```
Sub ShowNames()  
  Dim nmName As Name  
  For Each nmName In ActiveWorkbook.Names   
    nmName.Visible = True  
  Next nmName  
End Sub
```

Now, you can see again all names in Name Manager and delete them.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally arises when there are some erroneous names in the worksheet.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (the Excel name manager box will show up).  On the right hand side there will be a filter button - select "Names with error" and once all of them show up, delete the erroneous names.

Now try to copy the sheet.

Does it work?